# java click 2 buttons before an event

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and am wanting to create a small dice game. For the game, you roll two dice and then click a button from 1-9 based on the value of the addition or subtraction of the two dice. This works fine **except**, when I roll a 6 & 6 I want to be able to click on a 0 (for subtraction-which works) or a 1 & 2 together (for the addition of 12). I can only make my code for single value button clicks and not a 1 & 2. Any ideas on how to be able to click a 1 & 2 if I roll a 6 and 6?  (Code below for only buttons 0,1,2) Thanks for any help with this.

```
package dice;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Dice extends Frame implements WindowListener,ActionListener {
    TextField text = new TextField(20);
    TextField dice1 = new TextField(10);
    TextField dice2 = new TextField(10);
    TextField plusvalue = new TextField(10);
    TextField minusvalue = new TextField(10);
    Button b0;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    Button nomatch;
    Button rolldice;
private int numClicks = 0;
int dice1value;
int dice2value;
int SIDES = 6;
int plus;
int minus;
public void roll() {
    //roll dice
    dice1value = (int) (Math.random() * SIDES) + 1;
    dice2value = (int) (Math.random() * SIDES) + 1;
    plus = dice1value + dice2value;
    minus = abs(dice1value - dice2value);
    dice1.setText("Dice 1 = "+ Integer.toString(dice1value));      
    dice2.setText("Dice 2 = "+Integer.toString(dice2value)); 
    plusvalue.setText("Addition = "+Integer.toString(plus));      
    minusvalue.setText("Subtract = "+Integer.toString(minus));     
   }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Dice myWindow = new Dice("My Dice Game");
            myWindow.setSize(400,400);
            myWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Dice(String title) {

            super(title);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            addWindowListener(this);
            rolldice = new Button("Roll Dice");
            b0 = new Button("0");
            b1 = new Button("1");
            b2 = new Button("2");
            nomatch = new Button("No Match");
            add(b0);
            add(b1);
            add(b2);
            add(rolldice);
            add(text);
            add(dice1);
            add(dice2);
            add(plusvalue);
            add(minusvalue);
            add(nomatch);
            b0.addActionListener(this);
            b1.addActionListener(this);
            b2.addActionListener(this);
            nomatch.addActionListener(this);
            rolldice.addActionListener(this);
    }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

 if (e.getSource()==b0)
     {
         if(plus==0||minus==0)
         {  numClicks++;
            text.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
            b0.setEnabled(false);
     } else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't do that", "Error",
              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}}
 else if (e.getSource()==b1)
     {  if(plus==1||minus==1)
         {  numClicks++;
            text.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
            b1.setEnabled(false);
     } else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't do that", "Error",
              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}}
 else if (e.getSource()==b2)
     {
         if(plus==2||minus==2)
         {  numClicks++;
            text.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
            b2.setEnabled(false);
     } else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't do that", "Error",
              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}}
 else if (e.getSource()==nomatch)
     {
            numClicks++;
            text.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
                     }
 else if (e.getSource()==rolldice)
     {roll();


     } 

   }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            dispose();
            System.exit(0);
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be

```
    if (e.getSource() == b1) {
    if (plus == 1 || minus == 1 || plus == 12) {
        numClicks++;
        text.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
        b1.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't do that", "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}  if (e.getSource() == b2) {
    if (plus == 2 || minus == 2 || plus == 12) {
        numClicks++;
        text.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
        b2.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't do that", "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Or else you need to introduce a third variable for storing 2 and you need to check the value of the variable in the if conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this but if they roll a 6 & 6 I don't want them to be able to only click on a 1 or only a 2.....they have to click b1 and then b2 (and the code to wait and check once both have been clicked).....if I had a third variable I don't think I can run my code the way I have set it up as its only 1 button specific.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be adding another button such as "Done" after the player is done with clicking the numbers.

As the player clicks on the number, append the button value  to a String. So when button "1" is clicked, the String holds "1". If the player makes another click on button "2", the String becomes "12".

When the player clicks button "Done", parse the String to integer and compare against the expected answer and reset the String to empty.

If you don't want to implement the "Done" button, on every button click, increase a count variable by 1. If count is 2, trigger to check player's answer and reset count to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If I rolled a 6 & a 6 I get a bit lost as to what happens to button 1 when a player click on this first. It couldn't immediately get set as b1.setEnabled(false) in case they only clicked the 1 and tried to roll again. So the 'Done' works as the intermediary step to check I guess.....With the 'count variable' I also think I couldn't immediately set b1.setEnabled(false)... I think I need to think about this some more!